# adding SSL certificate for Github only (not all certificates from ca-certificates package)

Tags: git, ssl, certificates, github

I get the following error when accessing Github over HTTPS:

```
error: server certificate verification failed. 
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

This is because I don't have any certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs/`. I know how to fix this problem. I can install the package `ca-certificates` from Debian repository. The problem is, however, that this will install all certificates (thousands) which I don't necessarily want to accept/trust.

How can I install certificate for Github only?

#### a Subproblem/Subquestion

On another machine, where the package `ca-certificates` is already installed and git works, I have noticed that some certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs/` are one-certificate-per-file and other are many-certificates-in-one-file. The particular file containing Github certificate, `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` contains over 150 other certificates:

```
$ grep 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | wc -l
159
```

How can I find which one out of these 159 certificate is the one I need? (other than brute force - slicing the file in halves and checking both halves, repeating `while n > 1`).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Contacting GitHub programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source package and then extracting only the cert you want?

Comment: What are you using to access github? some command-line tool? a browser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to access your Github you need to do it via ssh. So you need to add your ssh public key to github. After that you are able to access github via ssh i.e.:

```
git init git@github.com:yourname/yourrepo.git
```

See also: [Github: generating ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Ssh-Public-Keys-on-Github)

[Edit #1]

without certificate checks:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://github.com/p/repo.git
```

or authenticated

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://user@pass:github.com/p/repo.git
```

For me it is still not clear what are you asking for, because you know that installing ca-certificates will fix the problem.

[Edit #2]

Ok, the other question was

> how to have only the certificate which is needed to access github.com via https

1. Open your browser and navigate to https://github.com/.
   Klick on the green name on the left from `https://` and klick on
   `Certificates`. On the `Details` tab, you'll see the 
   certificate chain, which is:

   ```
   DigiCert ...
     DigiCert ...
      github.com ...
   ```
2. Export each of the DigiCert certicates to a file.
3. copy the files to `/etc/ssl/certs/`
4. run `c_rehash` which cat all certificates to `ca-certificates.crt`
5. you are done.

As I said, I am not a friend of such actions because github can change the CA's anytime, 
so it will always result in additional work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I would like to access `github` via `https`.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested previously, you could use SSH keys, instead of relying on HTTPS to avoid this problem, and arguably, enjoy better security.

Having said that, I think what you are looking for is how to install root/CA certificates in /etc/ssl/certs. In a nutshell, it isn't sufficient to just dump the PEM-encoded file into /etc/ssl/certs - you also have to calculate the hash of said certificate, and create a symlink in /etc/ssl/certs to that cert file. The name of the symlink, has to be the hash suffixed by .0, or if there is a hash collision, .1, and so on.

Here's a detailed writeup, as well as a sample script you can use to automate the process:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wget-ssl-certs#adding.root.certificates

Hope this is what you were looking for, but like I said earlier, SSH keys are probably the "better" solution. :)

Comment: `c_rehash` is doing what you explained. See `c_rehash` man page. BTW: there is no need to calculate the hashes. Catting the certs to ca-certificates.crt is sufficient, since `git` reads only this file. Furthermore the link explained how to manually get the certificates with openssl. This is very doubtful and provokes a man in the middle attack. I wouldn't recommend it.